# How to ignore some fields when using snakeyaml to serialize java bean to yaml file

Tags: snakeyaml

I'd like to use snakeyaml to serialize java bean to yaml file. But I don't want to serialize all the fields of the java bean, some of them should be ignored. Is there any way to make it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by supplying a custom `TypeDescription`, with required exclusions, for that specific bean class. Let's say we have a bean like the below:

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {
    private String id = "x12345";
    private String firstName = "Test";
    private String lastName = "User";
    private String name = "Test User";
    private String dateOfBirth = "01-01-1970";
}
```

The code to exclude the `name` and `dateOfBirth` fields from the generated YAML would look like the below:

```java
import io.github.devatherock.domain.Employee;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions.FlowStyle;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.TypeDescription;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Tag;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer;

@Slf4j
public class TestUtil {

    public static String toYaml() {
        DumperOptions dumperOptions = new DumperOptions();
        dumperOptions.setDefaultFlowStyle(FlowStyle.BLOCK);
        Representer representer = new Representer(dumperOptions);

        TypeDescription typeDescription = new TypeDescription(Employee.class);
        typeDescription.setExcludes("name", "dateOfBirth"); // fields to exclude
        representer.addTypeDescription(typeDescription);

        // To disable the tag with class name
        representer.addClassTag(Employee.class, Tag.MAP);

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer);
        String result = yaml.dump(new Employee());

        LOGGER.info("Result: \n{}", result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The generated YAML would look like the below:

```yaml
firstName: Test
id: x12345
lastName: User
```